# New window redirecting to my homepage

Tags: javascript, html

Hey i have a problem with some code redirecting to my homepage. I have a registration page where when I click submit, it opens a new window welcoming you to the page. On this new window it has a link to go to the homepage, which works. What I'm wondering is can i somehow create a link on it that closes that window and makes the registration page I was on redirect to the homepage? Hope the question makes sense!

Comment: I'm lost...from what page to what you wanna redirect?

Comment: Short answer no, however you can close the first window when you click to go to the second, then have the second redirect to the home page.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith this seems like the best way with the responses I've gotten. How would I do this though? At the minute I have it where the new window opens but closes immediately.

Comment: Post your html for both pages and I will create an answer using javascript.

Comment: @ShaunaGoodmanFitzpatrick It's possible. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

A bit confused as to why you'd want to handle it that way. Could you just send them to the homepage after they click the submit link on the registration page? If so, you can do this with javascript by using document.location = "/";

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.opener` from the new window to access to its "parent" window. I just tested this, and it worked. Here's what I did:

#### index.html:

```
<button id='open'> Open </button>

<script>
    var btn = document.getElementById('open');

    btn.onclick = function (evt) {
        console.log('test');
        window.open('window.html', '', 'menubar=no');
    };
</script>
```

#### window.html:

```
<button id='close'> Close </button>

<script>
    var btn = document.getElementById('close');
    btn.onclick = function (evt) {
        window.opener.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
        window.close();
    };
</script>
```

- [MDN: window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener)
- [MDN; window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)
- [MDN: window.close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

Note: `window.opener` can be used maliciously, so be careful with it. [See this article for details.](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/)

Answer (score 0):

You can send messages between two windows using the postMessage API.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

When you are opening the new window, pass the reference of your current window as the data of the postMessage request to your registration window. When you are clicking on a button to cancel registration, before doing window.close, you can send another postMessage to the window reference you got earlier containing a message or boolean value to basically indicate that the user has cancelled his registration.

On receiving a message event, the original window performs a redirect to the home page